# How do you share Threat Plates profile imports?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am looking to share the [Threat Plates](https://wow.curseforge.com/projects/tidy-plates-threat-plates) WoW addon profiles to other people in my guild.

I have some guild members who have really nice Threat Plate and we want to be able to share the pre-set settings, but I cannot figure out how.  Is there a way to share these profiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always when dealing with files and settings: **Make a backup**!

Since most addons have no real export function you'll need the file containing all the settings. Unfortunately, ThreatPlates is no exception here.

You can find the saved settings of ThreatPlates here:

```
...\World of Warcraft\_retail_\WTF\Account\<your account>\SavedVariables
```

Your account ID can be your account's name (usually when you have an old account) or a number followed by a hashtag and another digit. That digit represents the license number and increases with multiple WoW accounts on one BNet account (WoW1, WoW2,... etc).

The settings files have the same (full) name as the addon on question. In this case it is:

```
TidyPlates_ThreatPlates.lua
```

and the same with the `.bak` extension, which serves as backup.

---

Case 1:

If you want the full config of another user you can safely replace yours with theirs. **Warning**: all your previous profiles will be gone, if you do so. Save your stuff before replacing it. **Close the game before you do it.** After doing so you'll still have to log on your character and click away the welcome note. Then go to Settings (`/tptp`) > Profiles and select your new profile from the dropdown.

---

Case 2:

In case you only want to copy a certain profile you should least have some basic understanding of how this kind of files work (LUA, JSON, etc). You can destroy your settings by doing it wrong. If you're not familiar with coding it might look messy.

Here is how you do it:

1. Create a replaceable profile in your addon. Give it a name you can easily find afterwards.
2. **Close the game** (that's important, otherwise it'll overwrite your changes again), open your file browser and open the settings file I've mentioned above.
3. Open the file in a proper text editor (I recommend Notepad++, because it can highlight the brackets) and find the following section:

   ```
   ["profiles"] = {   
   <lots of rows here>  
   }
   ```
4. Find the section with the name you have entered under #1:

   ```
   ["your profile name"] = {   
   <lots of rows here>   
   }
   ```
5. Open the source file from your friend and find the same portion of code under their profile name you want to copy.
6. Replace all the stuff between the main brackets (`["your profile name"] = { this stuff }`; keeping the outer brackets and name in place)
7. If you did it right you'll have your friend's settings in your profile options.
8. Log on your character, go to settings (`/tptp`) > Profiles and select your new profile from the dropdown, if you didn't already have it enabled before.